# TCPDF Codeigniter use multiple fonts

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, tcpdf

I managed to install a new font in TCPDF (Garamond.ttf). It includes bold and italic but it seems I can't use them both:

```
$font1=$this->pdf->addTTFfont('fonts/GARA.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$font2=$this->pdf->addTTFfont('fonts/GARABD.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);

$this->pdf->SetFont($font1, '', 7, '', false);
//$this->pdf->SetFont($font2, '', 7, '', false);
```

I render HTML code:

```
    $f1=$this->load->view('/pdf/FicheDecouverte.php',$data,true);
    $this->pdf->writeHTML($f1, true, 0, true, 0);
    //Close and output PDF document
    $this->pdf->Output('DomLoc', 'I');
```

It's either bold either normal. How can I use them both since my css `font-weight` property  seems to be ignored.

CSS:

```
.title {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 9pt;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #07636B;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. When I use HTML it's rendered all at a time and it seems everything is overridden by this line so I removed any font-set from my controller:

```
$this->pdf->SetFont($font1, '', 7, '', false);
```

Instead, using only css to define each font seems to work:

```
table {
    font-family: gara;
    font-size: 7pt;
}

.title {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 9pt;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #07636B;
    font-family: garabd;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this while trying to solve a very similar problem so here's the solution I found in case it helps anyone else.

For custom fonts where you have converted a font ready for TCPDF (there are online tools for this if you haven't yet) and dropped the resulting .php and .z files in the tcpdf\fonts folder, you can call them using inline-css by copying the exact name from the top of the font's .php file and using that as the font-family.

e.g. Top of myfont.php in tcpdf\fonts\

```
<?php
$type='TrueType';
$name='MyFont';
```

Inline-CSS use:

```
<div>Normal Text vs <span style="font-family: MyFont;">Text in my font</span></div>
```

Comment: Finally a working solution. Thanks a lot!